# Importing LCI database - dealing with unlinked exchanges

Tags: brightway

I am having an issue importing the ecoinvent v3.2 database (cut-off) in Brightway.

The steps followed were:

```
ei32cu = bw.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(fp, "ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff")
ei32cu.apply_strategies()
```

All seemed to be going well. However, `ei32cu.statistics()` revealed that there were *many* unlinked exchanges:

```
12916 datasets
459268 exchanges
343020 unlinked exchanges
Type biosphere: 949 unique unlinked exchanges
```

Of course, the unlinked exchanges prevented the writing of the database using `ei32cu.write_database()` did not work: an "Invalid exchange" was raised.

My questions:
- How can I fix this?
- How can I access the log file (cited [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/IO%20-%20importing%20Ecoinvent.ipynb)) that might give me some insights?
- How can I generate a list of exchanges (and their related activities)?

Answer (score 0):

It is strange you have unlinked exchanges with ei 3.2 cutoff, at least with python 3 should be very smooth importing 3.2 cutoff, are you perhaps on py2 or not using the latest version of bw2?

-difficult to give an answer without looking into the db, but if you are on py2 just try with the 3

-to check where the log is

```
`projects.logs_dir`
```

-to write the list of unlinked exchanges

```
ei32cu.write_excel(only_unlinked=True) #unlinked=False export the full list of exchanges
```

Comment: The logs file location should be printed out, as in the example notebook. In OS X, you can do e.g. `cd /foo/bar` and then `open .` to open this directory in the finder. Otherwise, you will have to navigate there yourself.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you should be able to run `bw2-update.bat` to get a more recent version of bw2io that includes the new biosphere flows added in 3.2. You will probably need to start a new project, as your existing biosphere database won't be automatically updated.

Comment: As fate would have it, I was unable to recreate the main problem - a new attempt imported fine. I am tempted to delete my question, but will leave it should others have a same (temporary?) issue and to give access to [Giuseppe Cardellini](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4929813/giuseppe-cardellini) and [Chris Mutel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/164864/chris-mutel)'s useful answers/comments.

Comment: To be clear, I was using Python 3 and had already updated bw2io, so the problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I now know *why* this problem occurred, and the solution is quite simple: in new projects, one needs to `bw2setup` *before* importing LCI databases.